# jQuery click event isn't fired when I click my image

Tags: jquery, events, click, image

Here's my `<head>`.

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />    
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda+Caption:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ddpowerzoomer.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready
            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })
        })

        $('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturetwo').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturethree').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturefour').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturefive').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

    </script>

</head>
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="auctiondetails">
    <img id="mainproductpicture" src="../../Content/Images/product2.JPG" alt="test" />

    <img id="smallpictureone" src="../../Content/Images/product1.JPG" />
    <img id="smallpicturetwo" src="../../Content/Images/product2.JPG" />
    <img id="smallpicturethree" src="../../Content/Images/product3.JPG" />
    <img id="smallpicturefour" src="../../Content/Images/product4.JPG" />
    <img id="smallpicturefive" src="../../Content/Images/product5.JPG" />

</div>
```

When click any of the images that's supposed to be wired for the event, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon after your jQuery(document)... call.

Comment: @ar: Missed that, thank you. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're binding those click events outside of your `DOMReady` hook, so those elements don't exist at that particular point in time.

Move them inside, and you'll be set:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready
    $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2, 5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
    });

    // Start binding events here...
})
```

Comment: Well that was it. Thank you for your help. I'd like to learn jQuery formally. Any books you'd recommend?

Comment: Sergio, I highly recommend you check out http://learn.appendto.com/.  They have some excellent quality free video tutorials on jQuery and JavaScript.  Also check out jQuery fundamentals http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html and Eloquent JavaScript http://eloquentjavascript.net/.  Both are free books that will really help you with your understanding of jQuery and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The click handlers are attached before the dom is ready so it will not work, try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready
            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })


        $('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturetwo').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturethree').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturefour').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

        $('#smallpicturefive').click(function () {
            alert('Handler for .click() called.');
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all .click bindings inside on-ready function:

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready`
...
`});

Your images are not there yet when selector searches by id.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to place your event handlers inside document ready:

```
$(function(){

//Place All event handlers here

});
```